# Hide/show an element in Angularjs using custom directive, ng-show and $scope

Tags: angularjs

When a link is clicked in the app navigation a dropdown with `ui-view` content shows below each respective link.

The HTML:

```
   <div class="sc-dash-header">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="navbar-brand" show-nav-popup href="">download</a>
        <div id="nav-download-progress" class="dash-hdr-popup" ng-show="showPopup">
          <div ui-view="hdr-download-progress"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="navbar-brand" show-nav-popup href="">add</a>
        <div id="nav-add" class="dash-hdr-popup" ng-show="showPopup">
          <div ui-view="hdr-add-content"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="navbar-brand" show-nav-popup href="">enter pin</a>
        <div id="nav-unlock" class="dash-hdr-popup" ng-show="showPopup">
          <div ui-view="hdr-unlock"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I've included an `ng-show` attribute to open the dropdown when `$scope.showPopup` is set to true.

To achieve this I've created a custom directive with an on click called `show-nav-popup`.

The JS:

```
.directive('showNavPopup', function () {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     // scope: {},
     link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      el.on('click', function(){
        scope.$apply(function () {
          scope.showPopup = true;
        });
        console.log(scope);
      });
     }
   };
 });
```

The above works, but the dropdown opens on each element.

Question: I need to isolate the scope, so on each click, only the respective dropdown appears. I uncomment the line `// scope: {}` - but this doesn't work..

Angularjs n00b here - any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I don't know your purpose, it seems worked, I just replace you ui-view with hard code content "aaaaaa", "bbbbbb", and "cccccc".http://plnkr.co/edit/U8BMJtBnyK1oxviMV9aL?p=preview

Comment: Because I need to isolate scope.. So they don't all appear at once.. Need to uncomment the line // scope : {} - apologies needed to be clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an isolate scope in this situation wouldn't fix the problem. There are a ton of ways to achieve what you want though. One of which is to assign each `show-popup-nav` an id, turn `$scope.showPopup` into an array, and keep an individual true/false for each id. Then for each ng-show, you look at the index corresponding to each id for the true/false value.

I coded it up on that guy's Plunker, working as you expect: http://plnkr.co/edit/CSikLIiuPNT9dfsfZfLk

EDIT: I should say, you COULD use an isolate scope to fix this, but that would require a lot of changes to your DOM, as the `ng-show` directive is a sibling to your `show-popup-nav`, and not a child.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the isolate scope, the scope applies to the element that your directive is applied to, and it's child elements. In this case that's just the anchor tag:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" show-nav-popup href="">download</a>
```

You are using an `ng-show` on a tag that is a sibling to the anchor tag:

```
<div id="nav-download-progress" class="dash-hdr-popup" ng-show="showPopup">
```

The sibling is not part of the isolate scope, and so it never notices that the value of `showPopup` has changed.

The `ng-show` would work if it were applied to a DOM element that was a child of the anchor tag.

**EDIT**

One way to make this work would be to wrap your two siblings in a parent tag, and use the directive on the parent:

```
<div show-nav-popup>
  <a href="#">Download</a>
  <div ng-show="showPopup"></div>
</div>
```

Then you'd need to modify your directive's code to find the anchor tag and apply the click handler.

You might instead try a completely different approach as suggest in the other answer by @Bill Bergquist